# Is the following code really currying in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand currying by reading various blogs and stack over flow answers and I think I understood some what. In Haskell, every function is curried, it means, when you have a function like
 `f x y = x + y`
it really is 
`((f x) y)`
in this, the function initially take the first parameter 'x' as the parameter and partially applies it to function f which in turn returns a function for y. where it takes just y a single parameter and applies the function. In both cases the function takes only one parameter and also the process of reducing a function to take single parameter is called 'currying'. Correct me if my understanding wrong here.
So if it is correct, could you please tell me if the functions 'two' and 'three' are curried functions?

```
three x y z = x + y + z
two = three 1
same = two 1
```

In this case, I have two specialized functions, 'two' and 'same' which are reduced to take only one parameter so is it curried?

Comment: You can test it by yourself using the `:t` command in GHCi (`:t three` will display the type of `three`).

Comment: @JoshuaHannah - maybe you see this here. I sureley meant no offense or for you to delete your answer - I just hoped you would add a bit usefull information for Nair - sorry man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at `two` first.
It has a signature of

```
two :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

forget the `Num a` for now (it's only a constraint on `a` - you can read `Int` here).
Surely this too is a curried function.

The next one is more *interesting*:

```
same :: Num a => a -> a
```

(btw: nice name - it's the *same* but not exactly **id** ^^)

*TBH*: I don't know for sure.

The best definition I know of a curried function is this:

> A *curried function* is a function of N arguments returning another function of (N-1) arguments.

(if you want you can extent this to *fully* curried functions of course)

This will only fit if you define constants as functions with 0 parameters - which you surely can.
So I would say *yes*(?) this too is a curried function but only in a *mathy* borderline way (like the sum of 0 numbers is *defined* to be 0)

Answer (score 4):

Best just think about this equationally. The following are all equivalent definitions:

```
f    x      y      z =  x+y+z
f    x      y =   \z -> x+y+z
f    x =   \y -> (\z -> x+y+z)
f = \x -> (\y -> (\z -> x+y+z))
```

Partial application is only tangentially relevant here. Most often you don't want the actual partial application to be performed and the actual lambda object to be created in memory - hoping instead that the compiler will employ - and *optimize better* - the full definition at the final point of full application.

The presence of the functions `curry`/`uncurry` is yet another confusing issue. Both `f (x,y) = ...` and `f x y = ...` are curried in Haskell, of course, but *in our heads* we tend to *think* about the first as a function of two arguments, so the functions translating between the two forms are named `curry` and `uncurry`, as a mnemonic.

Answer (score 1):

You could think that `three` function with anonymous functions is:

```
three = \x -> (\y -> (\z -> x + y + z)))
```